# dynamic sql query formation using pyhon

Tags: sql, python-3.x

I am new to the python and  want to form SQL query dynamically in python.so tried below sample code:

```
empId = 12

query = ''' select  name, ''' +
if empId > 10:
    '''basic_salary'''
else:
    ''' bonus'''
+ ''' from employee '''

print(query)
```

but , getting syntax error. does anyone knows how to form dynamic query in python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to indicate that the assignment to query continues on the next line, which you can do with a `\` at the end of the line. Also, you need to write the `if` statement as an inline `if` expression as you can't have an `if` statement in the middle of an assignment statement:

```
empId = 12

query = ''' select  name, ''' + \
        ('''basic_salary''' if empId > 10 else ''' bonus''') + \
        ''' from employee '''

print(query)
```

Output:

```
select  name, basic_salary from employee
```

If you have multiple conditions, you can just add to `query` in the conditions. For example:

```
empId = 6

query = 'select name, '
if empId > 10:
    query += 'basic_salary'
elif empId > 5:
    query += 'benefits'
else:
    query += 'bonus'
query += ' from employee'

print(query)
```

Output

```
select name, benefits from employee
```

Comment: Thanks @Nick, but what if I have multiple condition for empID or any other field, then will this possible to mention multiple condition in one line?

Comment: @SKP please see my edit. That should help with multiple conditions

Answer (score 1):

#dynamic sql query formation using python
#This is for PostgresSQL you can use this for other queries as well:

def updateQuery(self,tableName,setFields,setValues,whereFields,whereValues):
print("Generating update query started")

```
querySetfields = None
queryWhereFields = None

# Loop for set fields
for i in range(len(setFields)):
    if querySetfields is None:
        querySetfields=setFields[i]+"='"+setValues[i]+"'"
    else:
        querySetfields=querySetfields+","+setFields[i]+"='"+setValues[i]+"'"

# Loop for whereFields
for i in range(len(whereFields)):
    if queryWhereFields is None:
        queryWhereFields=whereFields[i]+"='"+whereValues[i]+"'"
    else:
        queryWhereFields=queryWhereFields+","+whereFields[i]+"='"+whereValues[i]+"'"

#Form the complete update query
query="UPDATE "+tableName+" SET "+querySetfields+" WHERE "+queryWhereFields

print("Generating update query completed")

return query
```

print(updateQuery(None,"EMPLOYEE_DETAILS",["EMPI_ID","EMP_LANID","EMP_NAME","EMP_EMAIL"],["A","B","C"],["EMPI_ID","EMP_LANID"],["X","Y","Z"]))